# Передать массив в хранимую процедуру (mysql, php)

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица с фотографиями:

```
create table `photo`
(
    `id`       bigint unsigned   not null auto_increment,
    `position` smallint unsigned not null default '0',
    primary key (`id`)
) engine = InnoDB
```

И код на php, который создаёт запрос для сортировки:

```php
$when   = '';
$photos = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]; // Задаётся извне
$photos_implode = implode(',', $photos);
foreach ($photos as $k => $v) {
    $when     .= " when " . (int)$v . " then $k ";
}
$query = "update photo set position = case id $when else position end where id in ($photos_implode)";
```

Получается запрос вида:

```
update photo set 
position = case id 
when 10 then 0 
when 9 then 1 
when 8 then 2 
when 7 then 3 
when 6 then 4 
when 5 then 5 
when 4 then 6 
when 3 then 7 
when 2 then 8 
when 1 then 9 
else position end 
where id in (10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

Существует ли элегантный метод реализовать такое с помощью хранимой процедуры?

Comment: Да не вопрос. Передаёте "массив" вот именно как CSV, и используете [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). PS. Версия MySQL - какая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE photo 
SET position = FIND_IN_SET(id, @new_order);
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef6ae22974a7d0dc35b46cff5a102cd2)</kbd>

PS. Предполагается, что в параметрах передаётся порядок для каждой имеющейся записи. Если какие-то записи отсутствуют в задаваемом списке, их `position` получит значение `0`.